# Can You Call a Single Python Command Without Entering the Python IDE in the Terminal?

Tags: python, bash, terminal

In the terminal you can type `python3` and it will dump you into the Python IDE to run your Python code. You can also type `python3 <python-file_name>.py` and it will run the aforementioned Python file. I thought that perhaps `python3` was simply a command, so I tried

```
python3 print("hello")
```

expecting the terminal to output `hello` similarly to just typing `echo "hello"`, but it did not. What I got instead was an error saying

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can you not run python code in the terminal in this way? Do you have to be in the Python IDE for this to work? Or am I missing a command option that would allow this?

Comment: @HenryEcker, that does! Thank you!

Comment: Note, that is not and IDE that is a REPL

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what’s “REPL”?